# json_encode adds double quotes when parsed

Tags: php, javascript, json

I am creating a JSON object in PHP like this:

```
echo json_encode(array("results" => array(array("user" => $member['user']),array("company" => $member['company']))));
```

In the JavaScript I get something like:

```
"{"results":[{"user":"David"},{"company":"something"}]}"
```

Then I try to validate this JSON and it is not valid, but when I remove double quotes at the beginning and at the end then it is validate JSON.

What am I doing wrong? 
This is how it should be:

```
{"results":[{"user":"David"},{"company":"something"}]}
```

EDIT:

part of my AJAX call:

```
success: function(response) 
        {
            for(var i=0;i<response.results.length;i++)
            {
              sessionStorage.setItem('user',response.results[i].user);
              sessionStorage.setItem('company',response.results[i].company);
            }
        }
```

Comment: How are you "trying to validate" the json? Also where do you get that json string from?

Comment: How your javascript code look like?

Comment: this should not be a problem if you echo javascript code (btw JSON stands for JavaScript Object Notation) with php, so obviously you are doing something wrong. Post your js code that uses this php echoed json.

Comment: How are you constructing the JS? Did you accidentally used `var json="<?php echo json_encode(...);?>";`?

Comment: I tested your code above and the result is like the result you want. Maybe you should show some more code like in the side of the javascript.

Comment: json_encode function in PHP takes an array - isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo json_encode(

array(
  "results" => 
     array(
        array("user" => $member['user'], "company" => $member['company'] ),
        array("user" => $member['user2'], "company" => $member['company2'] )
       )
     )
 );
```

Comment: what have you changed here? apart from indentation?

Comment: If you can see his json encode carefully, the structure is not correct
`array("user" => $member['user']),array("company" => $member['company']))` right??

Comment: possibly though its not my data so you would have to ask the @user123_456

Answer (score 9):

You appear to be double-encoding it. Either that, or you're encoding it and then dumping it inside quotes.

To be clear, you should have something like this:

```
var myJSobject = <?php echo json_encode(...); ?>;
```

Then it's good to go, nothing else needed.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like ur copying the string **with the quotes** from somewhere (from a log or something?), and trying to validate somewhere else. `echo json_encode(..)` should give u the correct Json string!